# How to find items where ID is not 1,2,3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create a list of items but in that list of items I need to make sure 3 of them are not in the list.

How do I achieve this in Rails?

I'm trying to get this to work:

```
not_droppable = [126,127,128]   
@items = Item.where('id not in (?)', not_droppable)
```

Comment: How are you storing the list? What do you actually need to do? Example code would probably help.

Comment: I fixed it. ID had to be in caps heh.

Comment: SQL is case insensitive (unless identifiers are quoted) so upcasing `id` almost certainly didn't fix your problem, something else is going on.

Comment: Nothing, it works now because I put the code in the controller instead of creating a scope. If I create a scope called "purchasable" and use it in the controller I get an "undefined method: purchasable" error :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@items = Item.all.delete_if {|x| not_droppable.include?(x.id)}
```

`Item.all` will always return an array. Use [`Array#delete_if`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-delete_if) to knock out `Item` elements from the collection whose `id`s are included in the `not_droppable` array.